# Jasmine Testing for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to override the variable value in jasmine testing but its not replacing.

**Sample.js**

```
v.ot ={ changeMe = true}
```

**Spec**

```
v.ot.changeMe = false;
```

Can anyone help me out to replace the variable value through jasmine testing.

Comment: Do you mean to do `v.ot = {changeMe = false};`?

Comment: What you posted isn't valid JavaScript... did you mean `v.ot = { changeMe: true }`?

Comment: In the Spec want replace the changeMe to false

Comment: Do so and perhaps remember the original value and reset the object to that value in a `afterEach()`.

Comment: Always getting changeMe as true and would like to change the value during testing spec